Having issue while creating external account
I have been working on integrating Stripe for fund transfers and successfully created an external account, receiving a token ID. However, when I attempt to perform a payout using this token ID, I encounter an error stating that the token ID is not valid.
What could be the reasons for this error, and how can I ensure that the external account is valid for the payout process? Additionally, what are the best practices for managing external accounts in Stripe to avoid such issues?
I expect the payout should be processed.

Have you tried opening a support ticket with Stripe?

Make sure that the key you're using is the correct one; e.g., if you are trying to create a manual payout in test, use your test key, otherwise your private key
